# How to show hidden div using url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a small page that has 3 sections. While 1 section is showing the others are hidden. When the page loads the welcome section is displayed, while the other sections are set to display:none. Clicking the menu button for the other pages shows the desired section and hides all the others; I am using jQuery to do that. Unfortunately, now I come across the problem that I'm unable to make a url to go to the specific section. Usually, to go to a section of a page that is not hidden, I would just create an anchor and name is XXX, and then add #XXX at the end of that page's url, but doing this on a hidden div doesn't make the div show.

Any suggestions?

html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <p><a href="#" id="menu-home">Home</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" id="menu-page1">Page 1</a></p>
    <p><a href="#" id="menu-page2">Page 2</a></p>
</div>

<div id="home">
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <p>This is where all the home page stuff will go</p>
</div>
<div id="page1">
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <p>Page 1 content here</p>
</div>
<div id="page2">
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <p>Page 2 content here</p>
</div>
```

css:

```
#page1 {
    display:none;    
}
#page2 {
    display:none;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu-home).click(function(){
        $('#home').show('fast');
        $('#page1').hide('fast');
        $('#page2').hide('fast');
      });
    $('#menu-page1).click(function(){
        $('#page1').show('fast');
        $('#home').hide('fast');
        $('#page2').hide('fast');
      });
    $('#menu-page2).click(function(){
        $('#page2').show('fast');
        $('#home').hide('fast');
        $('#page1').hide('fast');
      });
});
```

Comment: give us jsfiddle link of your code or paste your code

Comment: for some reason my jsfiddle won't use the jquery UI library so the show/hide functions are not working, but I've posted the sample in the questions above

Comment: I'd like to know if there is a way to point a user directly to #page1, without having to go to the home page and then selecting #menu-page1. xxx.com/home.html#page1 would work if the div wasn't hidden, but since it is hidden it seems to not work. Any way to trigger the jquery click function with a url?

Comment: to go to the specific anchor/id, just insert it into the link. the job can basicly be done in CSS http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoOBMB ##### jQuery has most of CSS selectors avalaible : http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)* which will return the corresponding part of the url.

For this to work you should give your `<a>` tags some proper hash value:

```
<p><a href="#page1" id="menu-page1">Page 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#page2" id="menu-page2">Page 2</a></p>
```

And check the mentioned string whether it matches a given page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //binding click events to elements

    var locationHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if(locationHash == 'page1'){
      $('#menu-page1').trigger('click');
    }else if(locationHash == 'page2'){
      $('#menu-page2').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

You see I used the click-events for a fast quick-n-dirty solution and also substringed `location.hash` to get rid of the `#`.
Of course this is open for improvement .e.g. not hiding page1 or page2 at all on page load if a given hash is found.

*See the linked document for [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) as window.location is a `Location` object which holds a `hash`property

Comment: Great answer, this really helped a lot. For some reason it triggers the click and starts the page in the middle of the actual page but that's no big deal. With a bit more tinkering I'm sure I'll figure it out. THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You will need some javascript, that, on page loading, checks the URL for an anchor like `#menu-xy`, and makes the corresponding `div` visible.