# Send someone the URL of a hidden div

Tags: javascript, html, url, hidden

So I hope someone can help. I'd like to send someone the url of a hidden div and have it open up for them complete with it's holding page.

My click event is in a list item in index.html such as:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" name="linkAbout" title="About" class="tablinks" 
      onclick="openScript(event,'about')">
        About
    </a>
</li>
```

and this gets revealed within the div with some javascript by:

```
<div id="about" class="tabcontent"> 
    <script>
        $( "#about" ).load( "pages/about.html", function(){
        });
    </script> 
</div>
```

My research suggests that I should be sending them something like:

- http://www.myserver.net/index.html#linkAbout (referencing the initial click href) or,
- http://www.myserver.net/index.html#about (referencing the hidden div)

but neither work as they only open the parent index.html page. Any clues? I know I could send them http://myserver.net/pages/about.html but that doesn't show all the styling and content etc. that's referenced from within index.html.

My thanks for your interest.

**Update - solved thanks** to [How to show hidden div using url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28396079/how-to-show-hidden-div-using-url) and @mplungjan

For those interested I created div id's for the clickable links then put the following in my head statements:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Binding click events to elements
        // Usage send a url to someone in the form http://myserver.net/#linkBenefits to open that specific page.
// Otherwise it will open http://myserver.net/#linkHome.

    var locationHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if (locationHash == 'linkBenefits'){
      $('#linkBenefits').trigger('click'),openScript(event,'benefits');
    }  else {
        $('#linkHome').trigger('click'),openScript(event,'home');
    }
});
```

Thanks @mplungjan and others for their interest.

Comment: The page at the end of the URL needs to see the # and understand it should unhide the div. If the page does not do that, then you cannot do what you want. Also your "about" has not rendered yet when you load the content in it.

Comment: just send a url with a parameter: then in your page check for the parameter. If it exists then set the div as visible. If not leave it as default hidden

Comment: Thanks both, I'm off researching a) sending parameters in a url - looks straightforward and, b) setting up my page to respond to them - looks a bit tougher!

Comment: This like a good starter - http://www.xul.fr/javascript/parameters.php thanks @Lelio